# Why is Apache responding to http://machineName

Tags: apache-2.2

I'd like to stop Apache from responding to

```
http://machineName.
```

I'd prefer it to respond (or redirect?) to

```
http://machineName.something.com
```

In my case,

```
http://intra-beta
```

should either repond or redirect to

```
http://intra-beta.domain.ca
```

Is this related to useCanonicalName ?

Here's a snippet of my httpd.conf

```
...

ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80

NameVirtualHost *:80

...

UseCanonicalName Off

...

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      intra-beta.domain.ca

    DocumentRoot "E:/web/intra/htdocs"
    ServerAdmin  admin@domain.ca

    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   intra.otherDomainFr.ca

    DocumentRoot "E:/web/intra/htdocs"
    ServerAdmin  admin@domain.ca

    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   intra.otherDomainEn.ca

    DocumentRoot "E:/web/intra/htdocs"
    ServerAdmin  admin@domain.ca

    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit #1**

This seems to work thus far...

```
RedirectMatch (.*) intra-beta.domain.ca$1
```

**Edit #2**

How about a situation like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "E:/web/inter-ssl/htdocs"
ServerName   inter-dev.domain.ca:443
ServerAdmin  admin@domain.ca

...
</VirtualHost>
```

If I do the modifications so that it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName inter-dev
    RedirectMatch (.*) inter-dev.domain.ca$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    #   General setup for the virtual host
    DocumentRoot "E:/web/inter-ssl/htdocs"
    ServerName   inter-dev.domain.ca:443
    ServerAdmin  admin@domain.ca

    ...
 </VirtualHost>
```

I get an error related with too many redirects. If I understand correctly, SSL works differently and this fix might not be a correct implementation in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly configure your redirect:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName intra-beta
  RedirectMatch /.* http://intra-beta.domain.ca
</VirtualHost>
```

In your case, every request whose `Host:` header doesn't match any of the configured `ServerNames` will be answered by the first `VirtualHost` whose IP address matches. Thus, if you put the above new `VirtualHost` at the first position in your configuration file, all requests whose `Host:` header is different from `intra-beta.domain.ca`, `intra.otherDomainFr.ca` or `intra.otherDomainEn.ca` will be redirected to `http://intra-beta.domain.ca`.

Comment: I might be getting greedy here, but is it possible to append the original querystring/path to the redirect?

Comment: Don't you get that in the `Referrer`?

Comment: this seems to work thus far RedirectMatch (.*) http://intra-beta.domain.ca$1

Comment: seems that applying this solution to ssl (or port 443) doesn't work. See Edit #2

Answer (score 0):

in /etc/hosts you got an entry

```
127.0.0.1   machine   machine.domain.com
```

or you have configured dns to assume local domain for each hostname and it is trying to resolve hostname with this local domain each time a hostname is in DNS query.

Comment: You cannot "configure DNS" to do that; it is a function of the machine 's local resolver library.